# how to have publishing, blog and wiki features together?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. I want to have blog and wiki features as well as publishing portal features. Any ideas how to integrate publishing portal, blog and wiki? For integrate, I mean using the same user name and password to pass through authentication of publishing portal, blog and wiki. And should I setup 3 different site collections for publishing portal, blog and wiki (I find if I setup publishing portal site collection, I can not create blog and wiki sub-site)?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problems at all with this. I just checked my SharePoint server with the publishing portal as the root of the site collection, and can create blog and wiki subsites with no problem.  No need to have separate site collections.  Where are you running into problems?